# Change Mapbox Navigation Control zoom icons color

Tags: css, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I managed to add the map navigation control, remove the compass and change the zoom control background and opacity.
But what about the '+' and '-' icons. How can you change the icons color, if you can?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the button images are set via the svg-files, they color can not be changed directly by the CSS-style. But you can specify a link to your external icons or override the fill color inside svg:

```
/** fill%3A%23333333 -> fill%3A%23ff0000 **/

.mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-in {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg%20viewBox%3D%270%200%2020%2020%27%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%27>%0A%20%20<path%20style%3D%27fill%3A%23ff0000%3B%27%20d%3D%27M%2010%206%20C%209.446%206%209%206.4459904%209%207%20L%209%209%20L%207%209%20C%206.446%209%206%209.446%206%2010%20C%206%2010.554%206.446%2011%207%2011%20L%209%2011%20L%209%2013%20C%209%2013.55401%209.446%2014%2010%2014%20C%2010.554%2014%2011%2013.55401%2011%2013%20L%2011%2011%20L%2013%2011%20C%2013.554%2011%2014%2010.554%2014%2010%20C%2014%209.446%2013.554%209%2013%209%20L%2011%209%20L%2011%207%20C%2011%206.4459904%2010.554%206%2010%206%20z%27%20%2F>%0A<%2Fsvg>%0A) !important;
}

.mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-out {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg%20viewBox%3D%270%200%2020%2020%27%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%27>%0A%20%20<path%20style%3D%27fill%3A%23ff0000%3B%27%20d%3D%27m%207%2C9%20c%20-0.554%2C0%20-1%2C0.446%20-1%2C1%200%2C0.554%200.446%2C1%201%2C1%20l%206%2C0%20c%200.554%2C0%201%2C-0.446%201%2C-1%200%2C-0.554%20-0.446%2C-1%20-1%2C-1%20z%27%20%2F>%0A<%2Fsvg>%0A) !important;
}
```

[ http://jsfiddle.net/7251btpy/ ]

Comment: wow. You deserve a lot of votes just for being able to decrypt the svg. haha. but where do you define the color? is the after `fill%3A%23`

Comment: works! where did you get the encoded svg from? I tried copying from the browser for mapboxgl-ctrl-fullscreen but cannot change fill as in your example

Comment: @GregHolst In the latest versions of the library, selectors for buttons are changed, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/g2oec786/

Comment: @stdob thanks, but works not in full screen for me, in general it seems to be a bug that I see the standard controls only in white as default, I posted it here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/7896

Answer (score 1):

Even if @stdob works well,
I got a solution with default svg images and a filter.

```css
.mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-in .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon,
.mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-out .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon {
  filter: invert(27%) sepia(51%) saturate(2878%) hue-rotate(346deg) brightness(104%) contrast(97%);
}
```

Works on compass and others icons too, but you have to set it on the icon not on the control, because the background color would be filtered too.

The source below will offer you a way to calculate the filter

source : https://css-tricks.com/change-color-of-svg-on-hover/

Answer (score 0):

Simple and best solution in css

perfect for north arrow.

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl-group{
    border-radius: 1px;
}
.mapboxgl-ctrl-group > .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
.mapboxgl-ctrl-group > .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon > button {
    width: 24px !important;
    height: 24px !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
}
.mapboxgl-ctrl-compass-arrow {
    margin: 0.1em 2px !important;
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNJ7P.png)

if you want to change the icon for zoom in and out control, modify these classes.

```
 .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon.mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-out {
background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZCAYAAADE6YVjAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABjSURBVEhLYxgFtAQOQHwRStMMtAPxfyhNMzBqCUlg1BIU4AjEHXjwcSAGWQKiscnDsD0Q4wSXgRhkCKUYlGFxApALsLkMhqniE0Jg6EQ8ITBqCUlg+FgCqxkpygejAA9gYAAASnVG42Lr1P0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=");}


 .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon.mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-in {
background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAuSURBVEhLYxgFo2AUjALSwVEg/k8hPgLEOMFhIMamiRQMMmMUjIJRMAqIBwwMALVbIvDMYvl8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to change the icons completely, here's a SASS solution if someone needs it in the future.

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl-group{
    //full screen buttom
    .mapboxgl-ctrl-fullscreen {
        .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon {
            display: none !important;
        }
        background-image: url(yourImagePath/image.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
    //shrink buttom
    .mapboxgl-ctrl-shrink{
        .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon {
            display: none !important;
        }
        background-image: url(yourImagePath/image.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
    //zoom in button
    .mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-in{
        .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon {
            display: none !important;
        }
        background-image: url(yourImagePath/image.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
    //zoom out
    .mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-out {
        .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon {
            display: none !important;
        }
        background-image: url(yourImagePath/image.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this. If you're wanting to style them in a dark theme, here's a simple solution:

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl-group {
  background: black
}

.mapboxgl-ctrl-icon {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

Here's a full example that also styles the scale control using Tailwind and CSS variables:

```
.dark .mapboxgl-ctrl-scale {
  color: hsl(var(--foreground)); // Alternatively, `white` or `#fff`
}

.dark .mapboxgl-ctrl-group,
.dark .mapboxgl-ctrl-scale {
  background: hsl(var(--background));  // Alternatively, `black` or `#000`
}

.dark .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

This pairs nicely with the new night theme from Mapbox Standard Style:

[image: Dark Mapbox Controls example]

Using a hacky css filter, I can get the icons to have a red overlay:

```
filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(300deg) saturate(600%);
```

Here's what that can look like combined with a custom background color and opacity:

[image: Mapbox controls with custom colors and opacity]